# need idea on strtok function?

Tags: c, strtok

hi friends am reading the data from the file and delimiting the value with the help of ','.
input file:

```
shankar,kumar,ooty
ravi,,cbe
```

code:

```
while ( fgets ( mem_buf, sizeof mem_buf, infile ) != NULL ) 
{
item = strtok(mem_buf,delims); 
printf("1 val:%s",item);    
item = strtok(NULL,delims);    
printf("2 val:%s",item);    
item = strtok(NULL,delims);    
printf("3 val:%s",item);
}
```

for the above input file output like:

```
1:shankar 2:kumar 3:ooty
1:ravi 2:cbe 3:
```

but i need output like,

```
1:shankar 2:kumar 3:ooty
1:ravi 2: 3:cbe
```

because in the input file for the second row middle data is null? could you please help me on this?
i know this happens because no space between ,, in the second row of input file?please tell me any other alternative way? or i should for alter the input file before it read?

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing stopping you from coding up your *own* `strtok`-like function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
```

```
static char *myStrTok (char *s, int c) {
    static char *nextS = NULL;  // Holds modified delimiter.
    static int done = 1;        // Flag to indicate all done.

    // Initial case.
    if (s != NULL) {
        // Return NULL for empty string.
        if (*s == '\0') { done = 1; return NULL; }

        // Find next delimiter.
        nextS = s;
        while ((*nextS != c) && (*nextS != '\0')) nextS++;
        done = (*nextS == '\0');
        *nextS = '\0';
        return s;
    }

    // Subsequent cases.
    if (done) return NULL;

    // Put delimiter back and find next one.
    *nextS++ = c;
    s = nextS;
    while ((*nextS != c) && (*nextS != '\0')) nextS++;
    done = (*nextS == '\0');
    *nextS = '\0';
    return s;
}
```

```
static int prt (char *s) {
    char *s2 = myStrTok (s, ','); printf ("1: [%s]\n", s2);
    s2 = myStrTok (NULL, ',');    printf ("2: [%s]\n", s2);
    s2 = myStrTok (NULL, ',');    printf ("3: [%s]\n", s2);
    s2 = myStrTok (NULL, ',');    if (s2 != NULL) printf ("4: [%s]\n", s2);
    printf ("==========\n");
}

int main (void) {
    char x[] = "shankar,kumar,ooty"; char y[] = "ravi,,cbe";
    prt (x); prt (y);
    printf ("[%s] [%s]\n", x, y);
    return 0;
}
```

This outputs:

```
1: [shankar]
2: [kumar]
3: [ooty]
==========
1: [ravi]
2: []
3: [cbe]
==========
[shankar,kumar,ooty] [ravi,,cbe]
```

as you desire. It only handles a single character for the separator but that appears to be adequate in this case.

Answer (score 2):

From the manpage: "A  sequence  of  two  or  more  contiguous delimiter characters in the
       parsed string is considered to be a single delimiter.  Delimiter characters  at  the  start  or end of the string are ignored.  Put another
       way: the tokens returned by strtok() are always nonempty strings."

So if you must use strtok, you will have to modify the input first somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the length of each `item` to make sure it's not 0.

Better yet, combine this with looping each line ([example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/)) so that you're not limited to three values.

Comment: I'm not sure that helps. The `,,` is coalesced into a single separator so you'll never _get_ an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

If `strtok` cannot do the job you want, you can code up your *own* parser, something along the lines of:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static int prt (char *s) {
    char *s2;
    s2 = strchr (s, ','); printf ("1: [%*.*s]\n", s2-s, s2-s, s); s = s2 + 1;
    s2 = strchr (s, ','); printf ("2: [%*.*s]\n", s2-s, s2-s, s); s = s2 + 1;
    printf ("3: [%s]\n", s);
    printf ("==========\n");
}

int main (void) {
    char x[] = "shankar,kumar,ooty"; char y[] = "ravi,,cbe";
    prt (x2); prt (y2);
    return 0;
}
```

That little sample shows you the difference between a `strtok` solution and a manual `strchr` solution, the output being:

```
1: [shankar]
2: [kumar]
3: [ooty]
==========
1: [ravi]
2: []
3: [cbe]
==========
```

You'll need to watch out for cases where you don't have enough delimiters (or too many) but that should be a minor modification.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a technique that I shamelessly copied from Rob Pike:

```
void print_tokens(char *s)
{
    char *p, *last;

    last = s;

    for (p = strchr(s, ','); p; p=strchr(p+1, ',')){
            *p = 0;
            puts(last);
            *p = ',';
            last = p+1;
    }
    puts(last);
}
```

I didn't test the above code, so there may be some minor flaws. The main idea should be clear, though.